# Exception when sending broadcast to ComponentInfo

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, push

I have a receiver for Google cloud message, it's registered in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.app.android.push.HSPushReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" />
            <category android:name="com.app.android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I can receive message when the app is in foreground or killed. However, if I start a IntentService with notification and then swipe the main activity away, then if I send a notification, I got the following crash:

```
08-29 15:29:37.782 W/BroadcastQueue(  757): Exception when sending broadcast to ComponentInfo{com.app.android/com.app.android.push.HSPushReceiver}
08-29 15:29:37.782 W/BroadcastQueue(  757): android.os.DeadObjectException
08-29 15:29:37.782 W/BroadcastQueue(  757):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
08-29 15:29:37.782 W/BroadcastQueue(  757):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
08-29 15:29:37.782 W/BroadcastQueue(  757):     at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleReceiver(ApplicationThreadNative.java:861)
08-29 15:29:37.782 W/BroadcastQueue(  757):     at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processCurBroadcastLocked(BroadcastQueue.java:245)
08-29 15:29:37.782 W/BroadcastQueue(  757):     at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processNextBroadcast(BroadcastQueue.java:898)
08-29 15:29:37.782 W/BroadcastQueue(  757):     at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue$BroadcastHandler.handleMessage(BroadcastQueue.java:149)
08-29 15:29:37.782 W/BroadcastQueue(  757):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-29 15:29:37.782 W/BroadcastQueue(  757):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-29 15:29:37.782 W/BroadcastQueue(  757):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
08-29 15:29:37.782 W/BroadcastQueue(  757):     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
08-29 15:29:37.782 W/libprocessgroup(  757): failed to open /acct/uid_10377/pid_3948/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
08-29 15:29:37.785 W/ActivityManager(  757): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.app.android/.HSNotificationService in 578824ms
```

HSNotificationService somehow got crashed. Somehow PushReceiver is dead when activity is swiped away. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found same problem in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535891/gcm-push-notification-for-background-app-causes-crash#comment52478944_31535891). Seems to be an Android bug reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53313) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=104308).

I used the workaround in [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53313#c1) and it's working for me. Someone said it has side effect though. [side effect](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53313#c16)

The workaround is to start a dummy activity in your foreground service

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved( Intent rootIntent ) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( this, ServiceKeepActivity.class );
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```